# Problemas com pesquisas mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Estou tendo um problema para fazer uma pesquisa no moongose, tenho uma função que faz pesquisas para todos os `ids` que envio porém quando passo o `id` entre `"5a01e1dbaf371d00152eae89"` funciona muito bem porém se passo pela função assim:

```
function getTripsLocation(line_id, index) {
  console.log(line_id);
  trip
      .aggregate([
          {
              $match: {
                  $and: [
                      {"_line._id": '"' + line_id.toString() + '"'},
                      {
                          "createdAt": {
                              $gte: new Date(moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00')),
                              $lte: new Date(moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:00'))
                          }
                      }
                  ],
              }
          },
          {
              $lookup:
                  {
                      from: "locations",
                      localField: "_id",
                      foreignField: "trip_id",
                      as: "local",
                  },
          }
      ])
      .then((data) => {
          if (data) {
              console.log(index, allLines[index]._id, 
              moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00'));
              index++;
              if (index > allLines.length - 1) {
                  finishProcess('Finish Task . . .');
              } else {
                  console.log(data);
                  setTimeout(() => {
                      if (data.length > 0) {
                          timeDifferenceCalculation(line_id, data,index);
                      } else {
                          getTripsLocation(allLines[index]._id,index);
                      }
                  }, 1)
              }
          }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('catch_error_on_trips', err));
  }
```

pelo `line_id` não funciona, e é o mesmo ID. Tentei colocat `.toString()` para verificar se era isto mais não tive exito.

Esta minha função `getTripsLocation` é recursiva !

O que pode ser e como corrigir ?

Meu objeto de linha no mongo está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `_line._id` é um ObjectId? se sim, tente passar a consulta dessa forma https://jsfiddle.net/cgxmtmy0/

Comment: Atualizei minha pergunta, porém ja tentei utilizar isto mais não funcionou bem

Comment: não seria `line_id._id` Renan?

Comment: Não consegui fazer aqui, tive que alterar minha colection e colocala como objetId ai funcionou.